# App that will pull data from website flash game

Tags: parsing, information-extraction

Basically I need information on how to pull data from a flash game webbased client and put that data into an app. The game is evony.com its a webbased flash game. I can probably figure out the coding such as parse the login and password and display the information in the app. What Im have major problems is following,

1. How can I find out what data in what format is being transmitted from
     webbased client to their server.
2. What software, preferably free, is out there that will do this for me?
3. Is there any tutorials, explanations, pointers anything describing this
     on the inet because I have searched high and low without success.

   I think the problem is because I am a beginner, I do not know the correct wording to serch for to find this information. It's a little like a needle in a haystack :) If you know what you want but dont know what it is called, get a new hobby :(

VERY much appreciated for any help, pointers, explanations, descriptions, tutorials or anything that can help me with this, very very much appreciated all.

/Core

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thats why Im asking it, your comment however is useless. As per the question it states I can probably solve the coding myself but I need help with the other stuff, hence I have not done anything with it as also per the question, I DONT KNOW WHERE TO BEGIN!

Comment: This question is not suited for Stack Overflow. Read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand why.

Comment: Seriously jurgemaister instead of filling up comments with useless comments, maybe help me out or dont comment at all. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: CoreCoder I'm with you on this. Nice question indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The tool of choice to get started is [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Its a software to monitor in- and outgoing datatransfer. It's very powerfull and a bit complex to get filtering right. Try something different to get started (e.g. do a ftp-login and try to "steal" your own password).

In Step two, you need to reverse engineer the communication between your client and the server. Thats the fun part. If it is encrypted, bad luck.

If you want to read the data, you can use libraries like [LibCap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to get the data in a language of choice. The flash player interacts with the game and you read the data transmitted.

If you are going for a stand alone program without the running flash client, you need to write your own client based on the protocol you got from step two. Be prepared to be kicked and banned permanently on the slightest error. I haven't checked on this one but every MMO I know and I can imagine do prohobit such tools.

Comment: First of all many thx for a response. I have been looking at WireShark for about 2 weeks atm and also been checkinig out LibCap. So looks like i have been on the right track. I know for sure this mmo does allow 3rd party software because there is a so called bot programs out there and there have been some android apps also but I am more interested in the learning to do this side of it all. But thank you again for the pointers.